# Cookies module not working in Electron app

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am trying to return the cookies from the browser header but I cannot even get the module to work. I can run the app but I am getting error message: [Error Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvEYo.png). I'm using Node.JS with Electron + Webpack + React. This is my code:

```js
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
var http = require('http');
var Cookies = require('./node_modules/cookies');
require('crash-reporter').start();

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('ready', function() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
   frame: true,
   width: 1200,
   resizable: false,
   height: 800,
    'web-preferences': {'web-security': false}});
  
  mainWindow.setMenu(null);

  mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/public/index.html');

  mainWindow.openDevTools();

  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
  
  mainWindow.on.session.Cookies.get({}, function(error, Cookies) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(Cookies);
  });
});
```

Package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "BSB-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "electron-cookies": "^1.1.0",
    "electron-packager": "^5.2.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.1.3",
    "less": "^2.6.0",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.2",
    "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.6.1",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.36.8",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "watch": "node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server",
    "electron-rebuild": "node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild"
  }
}
```

Webpack.config.js:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
  entry: { 
    app: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './javascripts/entry.js']
  },

  output: {
    path: './public/built',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/built/'
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/built/'
  },
  resolveLoader: {
      modulesDirectories: [
          'node_modules'
      ]
 },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }, exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'},
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)},
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
  }),
   new webpack.IgnorePlugin(new RegExp("^(fs|ipc)$"))
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [electron-cookies](https://github.com/hstove/electron-cookies) package it is meant to be used in the renderer process, you're attempting to use it in the main/browser process. In the render process you should be able to do something like:

```
require('electron-cookies');

document.cookie = 'key=value; key2=value2';
// or to clear the cookies
document.clearCookies();
```

Comment: I can see the cookies set by the fetch > post but when I do fetch > get (with credentials include) doesn't send the cookies.

Comment: The only way I could get Electron to send cookies when using fetch was to force the Github fetch polyfill [https://github.com/github/fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) over the top of the built in window.fetch.

Because the polyfill checks to see if the fetch function already exists, I had to extract the code out of node_modules and into my project, and then remove that check.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusRoberts !